# Should I close popup when use 'Back' key?

Tags: popup

What is the behaviour while using back(windows)/Delete(MAC) key when popup( using DIV) is open case?

[a] Go to previous screen and popup CLOSED

[b] Go to previous screen and popup is OPEN

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: We should Use "Esc" button to close a popup.
think of a scenario where you have few text fields in the popup and you need to delete the text...

Comment: Yes, always 'Esc' key for close a popup. But I am talking for using 'Delete' key when popup is opening.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the Delete key for closing a popup. Visitors could also use the delete key to delete text in a form in your popup / modal window. Stick to the ESC key and the known cross (X) on the top right corner.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most anticipated action (learned from other site's behavior) is to go to the previously displayed **page** (not modal state, not previous page with the modal open).

Of course this behavior could be changed if in this particular case is a proper UX justification for that, so that the change makes sense from the UX point of view.

Btw, I'm not sure, if it's possible to capture this button event; I think you would have to change links for all the modal states and use History API in HTML5, plus gracefully degrade it using history.js for older browsers.

So:

- Pros: possible UX improvement
- Cons: acting against default behavior, so against user expectations, so making them learn.

Personally, I would not do so. Instead, I would place previous/next buttons in the modal window, switching its states (I assume there are multiple steps in the modal).

Comment: Oslizio, Thanks for the quick reply. We will change background page to go to previous screen. but do we close the 'Popup' dialog when using 'DELETE' key.

Because, between background's previous page & 'popup' dialog context totally unmatched. That's why I have posted this question.

Comment: Maybe you should consider asking user if s/he wants to close the current page instead? The same way as it is on FB when you want to leave a page and have started typing in something?